# Distance or difference between two strings?

Tags: apex

So I'm looking for advice, because I've never quite done something like this before. Basically, a client has a field on their Opportunity that's called Semester, and its a string such as 2014-2-Fall. What they want, and this is my question, is that if someone changes it to say 2017-2-Fall(a 3 year interval) for another field to be updated.

Does anyone know how I can calculate the difference between these two strings in a trigger? I can write the logic to update the field myself I just need to know if A. This is possible. B. The best way to go about this.

Comment: Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you.  Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: Is the `Fall` bit normalized? What other values are there?

Comment: Once again, i'm NOT asking people to write anything for me, just direction. Please read above where i ask if this is possible and the best way to go about this. This could just be a reference via a link to someone who has had the same problem, or it could be just mentioning a specific method that'll do this in Apex. 

I'm not asking for anybody to write anything for me

Comment: @AdrianLarson there are basically all of the years until 2025 in two values, 2- fall, and 1-Spring

Comment: Take the Left 4 of the strings, convert them to numbers and do the math. All the while checking for null, NaN, etc. one approach.Really depends not he normalization of your data

Answer (score 6):

I'd say, there are two obvious ways.

First is using the [Apex String API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) `String.getLevenshteinDistance()`. I'll be honest with you...I know nothing about this, apart from the name is cool, and it uses some algorithm (ostensibly created by someone named "Levenshtein") to identify the mathematical difference between one string and another. But you can read the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) about that if you want to see if you can use it.

My guess is that it might not be quite exactly what you're after.

The other, is (provided the format is always just as you state) to split the String using the `-` character, break it into elements, say in a plain-old-apex-object, and create some logic to determine the differences.

```
String semesterString = '2014-2-Fall';
List<String> semesterElems = semesterString.split('-');
```

Now you have a list where

```
semesterElems[0]  --> '2014'
semesterElems[1]  --> '2'
semesterElems[2]  --> 'Fall'
```

It's not too far from here to stuff that data into an object, set correct types, and then be able to test differences between the different elements.

The downside here is if anyone ever enters that semester value in a different format in the future, things will start breaking. So best also set up some validation rules and check ahead of time to ensure that existing data is clean and will support this.

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna give this a go and also check into the ApexStringAPI and see if that is along the lines of what I'm looking for. I appreciate it!

Comment: *Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other. It is named after Vladimir Levenshtein, who considered this distance in 1965.*